# RStudio saving plots automatically

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I don't know why but my RStudio is saving all the plots I do into the current directory instead of showing them at the Plots section.

Anyone with similar experience or ideas on how to get rid of that "feature"?

Comment: Are you making the plots with base R, ggplot, or something else? One of the reasons I prefer to use ggplot, even for very simple plots, is that it has a `ggsave` function for cleanly exporting plot objects as images.

Comment: one reason plolts may not be showing up is because it's taking huge time to render the plots .. therefore RStudio might be saving it in the current directory instead .. though this is just an assumption ..

Comment: I have never encountered that behavior. Can you give a simple reproducible example?

Comment: @JohnColeman I think is something in my RStudio, and I have no idea what it is. So I really don't know how to make it reproducible :/ Sorry about that. But it happens even if I just do x <- c(1,2,3,4); plot(x); It simply appears in my folder and never in RStudio

Comment: Maybe try RStudio's support - http://community.rstudio.com/ ?

Comment: @RaquelRgg: Try to update your R and R Studio.